# Does it make sense to use useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have simple functional component which I'm trying to optimize. I have a table with buttons in one column, button is separate component. I need to pass callback function to this component and I'm trying to do it with useCallback hook. But I need to update some dependencies values in this callback. If I leave them in dependencies useCallback will leave sense, because callback function will be created everytime. If I remove them(hiddenField, amountField) from dependencies I will get old previous values for them everytime when selectItem is called and if condition evalustes to "false"(I really don't understand why). Does it make sense to use useCallback in my case?

```
export function TestComponent({ field, hiddenField, amountField, changeField }) {
    const selectItem = useCallback(() => {
    const fieldId = field.attributes.Id;
    if (hiddenField.get('id') !== fieldId) {
        changeField(hiddenField, fieldId);
    }
    changeField(amountField, field.attributes.amount);
  }, [field.attributes.amount, field.attributes.fieldId]);// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
return (<ButtonComponent field={field} click={selectItem} />);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I veryfied that the cause of using old values in callback function is clousure. And for getting new values I need to add hiddenField, amountField as useCallback's dependencies. But if I do that - wrapping callback in useCallback will be useless, because selectItem  function will be created on each render anyway